# PYPATH No registry key error on installing Gaphor with Python

Tags: python

I have downloaded setup exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gaphor. I am already having installation of Python2.7, PyGTK (Complete package). So when I start the install, I deselect Python2.5, PyGtk etc (as I already have python2.7). But as soon as I begin installation, I got the error:

> PyGtkGUI can't be installed as Python not found on this system. PYPATH = No Registry key found.

NOTE: 
I am able to proceed, actually i downloaded source code and build it and is working from there. However i would like to know the solution for the original problem reported.

Answer (score 2):

you must add an environment variable

http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

and use official site wiki:

https://github.com/amolenaar/gaphor/wiki/Custom-Python-Installation-Location